# What is the offset function returning in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I go through the code and I just do not understand what is the `offset` function returning:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
  $('#goto-show-form').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#show-form").offset().top}, '500');
      $('#first-field').focus();
      return false;
  });
});
```

Please explain the `offset` function and how it works and what it returns. So what is it returning in:

```
$("#show-form").offset().top
```

What is the difference between a `div` top and `offset` top?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the function in jQuery? http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's offset() function returns the left and top of the element with respect to the document left and top.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) was written for this:

> **`.offset()`**
>
> ***Description**: Get the current coordinates of the first element in the
>   set of matched elements, relative to the document.*

Your line of code calculates the vertical position of the element relative to the document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").css("top");
```

Will return the `div`'s `top` property in the CSS (if it is defined).

```
$("div").offset().top;
```

Will return the `div`'s offset relative to the page, no matter what it's top values is in CSS.